# no compatible version of visual studio net found on system

Tags: visual-studio-2010, activereports

I have installed full version licensed Visual Studio 2010 Professional, .Net 4.0 on my system. Now I am trying to install Active Reports 6 on it and facing the error "no compatible version of visual studio net found on system". My Active Reports build is 6.0.1.1797.0.

So, do I need to install framework 3.5 before installing? I have not installed Service Pack for visual Studio for now.
Thanks.

Comment: Long shot: have you actually started up Visual Studio? At least in older ones that made a difference for installing the Platform SDK. What does your Active Reports build say that it's compatible with?

Comment: "no compatible version of visual studio net found on system" this i the error. I have started Visual Studio already

Comment: Thanks - I meant what does the release note say, or the product web page, or whatever documentation you have. Does it say "Compatible with Visual Studio 2010" or just 2008 or something else? i.e. can you actually expect this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active reports 6.0.1797.0 does not support Visual Studio 2010. Active reorts 6.1.2577 or later supports Visual Studio 2010. And any how, Express edition of visual studio does not support active reports.

So my solution, enhances...I installed the later versions...but unfortunately I am getting some errors in my application because of Active reports version change as my application was made in previous version of Active Reports. So, what I did is, installed the latest version, uninstalled it and again installed 6.0.1797.0 version, and it was installed successfully and my application was also working fine.

Comment: Also, since you are starting out with 6.1.2577, you may want to just upgrade to SP2 of ActiveReports. Here's the version history: http://www.datadynamics.com/Forums/83/ShowForum.aspx

Answer (score 1):

@rapsalands...You are correct in understanding that support for Visual Studio 2010 started only after build 6.1.2577.0 was released. Also express edition of Visual Studio is not supported. The first thing to note here is that whenever you install/uninstall ActiveReports 6 from your machine, there should be no running instance of Visual Studio as it affects proper integration of ActiveReports with itself.

Also the errors which you were getting are more likely appearing because of the incorrect references in your project. Whenever you open an existing project after upgrading ActiveReports build, you should remove all the ActiveReports references from the project, re-add them (making sure they point to the version currently installed) and finally rebuild your project.

I think you can also check the [blogs](http://www.gcpowertools.info/) for ActiveReports as you might find some useful information about different topics there.